# Life develops on a moon left in darkness?

Tags: science-based, xenobiology

In the deep, outer reaches of our galaxy, there is a rogue gas giant which, due to an unfortunate event, was flung from its native orbit into interstellar space. It has a mass 12 times that of Jupiter, approaching the title of Brown Dwarf.

It has only 2 moons, one of which developed life during its time in its native system. The larger moon has a mass which is about 1/2 of the mass of Earth and is close enough to its parent planet that it is under constant stress from tidal heating.The other moon is much farther out and is comparable in size and mass to Mimas.

The main moon has an atmosphere which is comprised of almost equal parts of oxygen and nitrogen, with about %0.01 of its mass being water.

**Could life continue to be sustained after the planet's ejection from the system?** And an additional and secondary question, what would be the effects on this ecosystem if it re-entered another star system?

Comment: In the underground of moon, if the moon has some heat from core, like life expected to exist in Enceladus, or even some hypothesis about Pluto, yes.

Comment: I saw a documentary on this. I can't remember what it was called. If I can find the name, i might do the question. If the energy for life came from the almost-brown dwarf before (chemical, tidal, etc.), lack of a star is completely inconsequential.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For life as we know it, the presence of liquid water is mandatory.

Once you have liquid water, you need a source of energy, or better of low entropy: this can be a star, a geothermal vent, whatever.

If the above two conditions are met, there might be life, and if life was present, it might be sustained.

However mind that the transition from star sustained to something else sustained cannot happen from one day to the other, this poses some constraints on the timeline of your world before present: either non stellar sustained life was already present, or it slowly adapted to the new conditions.